# Copy a PostgreSQL database into another database

Tags: postgresql

How to copy (or create new one and copy) a PostgreSQL database to another (new) database?
Is there any query based method for doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This:

CREATE DATABASE newdb WITH TEMPLATE olddb;

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: but this is what OP asked for - copy whole database

Comment: Its the same I need. Thank you Thush.