# Copying a postgresql database through ssh

Tags: postgresql, ssh

First off, this is based on 
[Copy a PostgreSQL database into another database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693921/copy-a-postgresql-database-into-another-database). I would gladly expose my problem there, however I have not enough Karma yet to do so.

Here's my code :

```
sourceDB=$1
targetDB=$2

ssh mgf "createdb $targetDB"
pg_dump -C "$sourceDB" | ssh -C mySSHalias "psql $targetDB"
```

Here's the output :

```
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
ERREUR:  la base de données « mySourceDB » existe déjà
ALTER DATABASE
\connect : option de connexion « -reuse-previous » invalide
```

So basically my first command is creating a database with $targetDB's name, while my second command try to create a database with $sourceDB's name ?

How to restore at the other end of the pipe with a different name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the `-C` flag in `pg_dump`.
This flag causes a `CREATE DATABASE` statement to be added to the dump file, which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: I am so dumb... Thank you so much !